# DomainClassMarchaller doesn't recognize the persistentEntity working for Grails 4.x

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm

I have tried different approach by now and none of them has work.

here is the code that should work based on grails 4.x

```
class DomainClassMarshaller {
    def grailsDomainClassMappingContext
    public static final List<String> appendFields = ['id']

    static Closure appendMarshaller(String clazz, List<String> fieldsToInclude) {
        return { domainItem ->
            def domain = grailsDomainClassMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(clazz)
            def results = [:]
            domain.persistentProperties.each { field ->
                results[field.name] = domainItem[field.name]
            }
            def fields = []
            fields.addAll(appendFields)
            fields.addAll(fieldsToInclude)
            //println "size:" +fields.size();
            fields.each { name ->
                results[name] = domainItem[name]
                //println "name :"+name+" value:"+domainItem[name];
            }
            return results
        }
    }
```

I tried using `grailsApplication.mappingContext.getPersistentEntity(object.getClass().getName())` but that didn't work

Error:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: grailsDomainClassMappingContext for class: com.opentext.pap.utils.DomainClassMarshaller
Possible solutions: grailsDomainClassMappingContext
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1021)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1866)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1842)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3797)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:193)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyTryThese(Closure.java:313)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyOwnerFirst(Closure.java:307)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.getProperty(Closure.java:296)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:309)
```

if you have any suggestions will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference an instance property from a `static` method.  The JVM won't (and shouldn't) allow that.  `def grailsDomainClassMappingContext` is an instance property and `appendMarshaller` is a static method.  You will see a similar problem if you do this:

```
class Something {
   def someProperty
   static void someMethod() {
        println someProperty
    }
}
```

Comment: I was playing around with the signature of the method and apparently needs to be static... how can I call a instance property from a static method?

Comment: "how can I call a instance property from a static method?" - You can't.  The JVM does not allow it.

Comment: It isn't exactly clear why your `DomainClassMarshaller` class exists but it looks like the app may be taking a somewhat complicated approach to configuring marshallers.  I know you didn't ask about how to do that in particular, but if you post that as a question, I think you will get some good ideas that are better than using this static method.

Comment: thank you @Jeff Scott Brown, I created an new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66887291/how-to-configure-a-domain-marshaller-on-grails-4-x

Comment: @GlenGil I see that the code you posted over there is different, and that code has a different set of problems than the code shown in this question.

Comment: I was trying to get it working this is my first time working with Groovy in general, and I don't really know what is this DomainClassMarshaller for. So, a lot of learning